# Variable cannot appear in expression, for array dimension and variable declaration

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to write a subroutine that has a do-loop that loops until a given number of loops. since this constant is repeated throughout the code I want to change the constant for a variable. for example instead of do i=0, 3 I have do i=0, dp. this works on the do loop but in this loop I am filling an array called price and name only problem is that I cannot set the array lengths to this variable. I am using fortran force and saving it as .f95.

here is the code I am using

```
   subroutine Aula()
   !implicit none
   integer :: dp=3 !Array length
   real :: Price  ! price of obj
   character(len=20) Name(3) !name of obj
   dimension price(dp)

   do i=1, dp
      write(*,*) "Name"
      !waits until all vectors are cleared
      read (*,*) Name(i)

      write(*,*) "Product"
      !waits until all vectors are cleared
      read (*,*) Price(i)
   end do

   do i=1, dp
      write(*,*) Name(i), Price(i)
   end do
   end subroutine Aula
```

my doubt about variable declaration is because of my professor what is the difference between declaring a variable like this integer dp or like this integer :: dp (my professor said she never saw something like this but she also said in our 4th class that fortran is case sensitive, which it isn't, so... she doesn't help at all). so what is the difference between using :: or leaving the declaration with out it?

Comment: In your case the `::` is necessary (because of the `=3` after the variable name), but that's not your real problem.  Instead, you need to find a way to make the array size not constant: that's what the linked question is about.

Comment: _Said that Fortran is case sensitive_... Sorry about your professor.

Comment: thanks francescalus, but what does the :: do exactly? I cant find an explanation anywhere and I dont know the name of the operator.
Rodrigo, ya my professor said that she discovered fortran 95 a few years ago so, I just have to be able to justify whatever I use to be able to deal with her...